# is there package exist in python to do RWR(random walk with restart)

Tags: python, python-3.x, random-walk, weighted-graph

is there some package or function that to compute RWR in python?
i want to compute RWR using weighted graph.
but i can't find RWR package in python.
plz tell me that package name if exist in python.
or please see me some example RWR in python.
thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you start here [cookbook BrownianMotion](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/BrownianMotion)

Comment: @AskingQuestions thanks a lot!

Comment: @AskingQuestions you're encouraged to submit your answer for acceptance rather than using comments. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you start here: [SciPy Cookbook » Other examples » Brownian Motion](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/BrownianMotion.html).

If you are really looking for a comprehensive package, you might want to check out [MMTK](http://dirac.cnrs-orleans.fr/MMTK/). But to be honest that is probably not what you are looking for (as it comes more from a Molecular Dynamics approach). There is no library for random walks for the simple reason that the integrator for the stochastic differential equation is easily written in 3 lines (by drawing random numbers from a normal distribution and adding them each step).

As of 2021 there is now a random walk library for python which is found here: [pyrandwalk](https://github.com/sadrasabouri/pyrandwalk)